# Why does not PHP part Javascript work in PHP section, But works fine in Html Section?

Tags: javascript, php, variables, echo, alert

I am beginner in web development and know basic things. When creating project for practice implementing JavaScript in PHP file got stuck in this issue of putting PHP variable in the JavaScript. I am using apache xampp for PHP.

```html
<?php  
$name = "Mack Mack";
echo '<script>alert("<?php echo $name ?>");</script>'; 
/* this show <?php echo $name ?> */
?>

<html>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <body>
    <h1>welcome</h1>
        <div id="divid">check javascript</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("divid").innerHTML += ' running';
            alert("<?php echo $name ?>" + " from the html script section" );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the alert works fine for the PHP variable in the html section scripting, but doesnot work as expected in PHP section.

Comment: Use concatenation in PHP. Replace `echo '<script>alert("<?php echo $name ?>");</script>';` with `echo '<script>alert("' . $name . '");</script>';`

Comment: Also try `echo "<script>alert('$name');</script>";`

Comment: it also works fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: Yes, it worked. i am just a learner so have not covered all the basic in PHP and JavaScript. Thanks for the care